# Magento 2 delete search term through sql query

Tags: magento-2.1, database, sql

I want to delete search terms with 0 search results from magento 2 database by writing sql query in file. How can I do this?

Comment: We do have an option delete the search terms from the admin , On the Admin sidebar, tap Marketing. Then under SEO & Search, choose Search Terms. here we have option to filter results in the grid and delete it.

Comment: I want to create a file in magento which I will run through cron job everyday to delete the search terms automatically.
I am asking for solution in code file.

Comment: Delete the records from the 'search_query' whose 'num_results = 0'.

Answer (score 2):

The query should be like,

```
DELETE FROM `search_query` WHERE `num_results` = 0;
```

Or you can use following PHP code.

```
protected $queryCollectionFactrory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Search\Model\ResourceModel\Query\CollectionFactory $queryCollectionFactrory
)
{
    $this->queryCollectionFactrory = $queryCollectionFactrory;
}

public function removeZeroResults()
{
    $collection = $this->queryCollectionFactrory->create();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('num_results', 0);

    foreach($collection as $row)
    {
        $row->delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: where to place the above php code file ?  I mean to say the path . Do I need to create a custom module for this ?

Comment: You can create a custom module or you can place this code on whatever event you want to delete records with 0 search result.

Answer (score 0):

Select * FROM `search_query` WHERE 'query_text' LIKE '% textYouWant%'

once you see the values then you can do this :
Delete FROM `search_query` WHERE 'query_text' LIKE '% textYouWant%'